# Is there a NoSQL alternative to SQLite for flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, nosql

I am building a standalone(no API calls to MongoDB or Firebase etc.) flutter app for which database management is crucial. Currently, I am storing it as JSON, but it's simply inefficient. I cannot use SQLite because the data are very nested, in fact, JSON is the only way to store my data. So, I am looking for a NoSQL alternative.

This is the data model I want to store.

**lib/book_model.dart**

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Book {
  /// Do not change this. It's a primary key.
  String bookLink;
  String authors = null;
  String thumbnail = null;
  String bookName = null;

  List<Chapter> totalChaptersList = [];

  ///todo: determine datatype
  var currentChapter;

  String summary = null;

  double rating = 0.0;

  List<String> genres = [];
  Book({
    this.bookLink,
    this.authors,
    this.thumbnail,
    this.bookName,
    this.totalChaptersList,
    this.currentChapter,
    this.summary,
    this.rating,
    this.genres,
  });

  Book.generateFromSearchBook(SearchBook searchBook) {
    this.authors = searchBook.authors;
    this.bookLink = searchBook.bookLink;
    this.bookName = searchBook.bookName;
    this.thumbnail = searchBook.thumbnail;
  }

  // @override
  // String toString() {
  //   return "<$bookLink , $authors , $thumbnail , $bookName , $summary , $genres , $rating , $totalChaptersList , $currentChapter>";
  // }

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BookFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BookToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Chapter {
  String name = null;
  String date = null;
  String chapterLink = null;

  @JsonKey(defaultValue: false)
  bool has_read = false;

  List<Page> pages = [];
  
  Chapter({
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.chapterLink,
    this.has_read,
    this.pages,
  });

  // @override
  // String toString() {
  //   return "<$name , $date , $chapterLink , $has_read , $pages>";
  // }

  factory Chapter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ChapterFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ChapterToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Page {
  String pageLink = null;
  int pageNumber = 0;
  Page({
    this.pageLink,
    this.pageNumber,
  });

  // @override
  // String toString() {
  //   return "<$pageLink , $pageNumber>";
  // }
  factory Page.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PageFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PageToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Will this fit your use case Hive - https://pub.dev/packages/hive ?

Comment: If the data is nested, you will have to go with any of the databases of MongoDB or firebase only, else you will have to work with JSON, but if the data becomes large you will surely suffer memory leaks, Maybe will have to find a way to split the data maybe then.

Comment: Recently I faced the same issue; I still not found a NoSQL database like Mongo that can replace Sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found these two

- [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)  - Hive is a lightweight and blazing fast key-value database written in pure Dart. Inspired by Bitcask.
- [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) - ObjectBox is a super-fast database storing Dart objects locally.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). It's fast and easy to use.you can use [hive_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator) with *json_serializable* and *freezed* to create a **HiveObject** class.

example:

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Person extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;
        
  @HiveField(1)
  int age;
}
```

You can also use [hive_box](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter) to turn your hive box into a listenable and listen to database changes.

example:

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box('settings').listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, widget) {
        return Switch(
          value: box.get('darkMode'),
          onChanged: (val) {
            box.put('darkMode', val);
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```